# TR not Moving to Next Line

Tags: html, html-table

```
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
          <th colspan="4">Seminar</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Schedule</td>
          <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Topic</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="1">Begin</th>
          <th colspan="1">End</th>
        </tr>

        <!--MONDAY-->

        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">Monday</th>
          <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
          <td rowspan="2">5:00 am</td>
          <td>Introduction to XML</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
        </tr>

        <!--TUESDAY-->

             <!-- ROW 1 -->
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="6">Tuesday</th>
    <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">11:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="3">XPath</td>
  </tr>

  <!-- ROW 2 -->
  <tr>
  </tr>

  <!-- ROW 3 -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">11:00 pm</td>
    <td rowspan="2">2:00 pm</td>
  </tr>

  <!-- ROW 4 -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">XSL transformations</td>
  </tr>

  <!-- ROW 5 -->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2:00 pm</td>
    <td rowspan="2">5:00 pm</td>
  </tr>

  <!--WEDNESDAY-->
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="1">Wednesday</th>
    <td rowspan="1">8:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="1">12:00 pm</td>
    <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
  </tr>



      </table>
```

Soo I was making this timetable for my seminars for no reason at all and Wednesday is not moving to the next row. Any ideas on how to fix this?? I tried 
 already and tried copying the first row to the last to edit it so that it fits the third row's context. I don't understand why this is happening can u pls help?
[here's a link to the picture to my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94gSx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fix the mismatched tag `<th colspan="2">Schedule</td>` so it reads `<th colspan="2">Schedule</th>`.

It's the row spans that are tripping you up, particular for Tuesday.  You say Tuesday has a span of 6, but you only have 5 rows.  Still not sure what you want but what about this?

```html
<style>
table, tr, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
</style>

<table>
<tr>
    <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
    <th colspan="4">Seminar</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">Schedule</th>
    <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Topic</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="1">Begin</th>
    <th colspan="1">End</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Monday</th>
    <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">5:00 am</td>
    <td>Introduction to XML</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th rowspan=6>Tuesday</th>
    <td rowspan=2>8:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan=2>11:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan=3>XPath</td>
</tr>

<tr></tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2>11:00 pm</td>
    <td rowspan=2>2:00 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=3>XSL transformations</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td rowspan=2>2:00 pm</td>
    <td rowspan=2>5:00 pm</td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>

<tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Wednesday</th>
    <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
    <td rowspan="2">12:00 pm</td>
    <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: look at the output ull understand

Comment: I obviously looked at the output to debug this for you.  As you did not tell us what you wanted I made an educated guess.  Pointing this out in case I guessed wrong.  Options that I considered were a leave the slot open (XLS Transformations) is the only one that spans two timeslots, combine the two time slots into one, span two slots.  Please upvote the answers that were helpful to you, and accept an answer if you are all set.

Comment: I'm trying to get XPATH and XSL transformations to be equal in rowspan. Thats what I'm trying to achieve. Both the answers as of yet have made one of them big..

Comment: What does that mean?  You have 3 time slots so you want XPATH and XSL to span 1.5 row?  Maybe an image might be helpful so we can figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Updated my answer.  I still don't know what you want, but that's my best guess.  You make it hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of wrong usage of rowspan and colspan. They can't used for the purpose of spacing.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Day</th>
        <th colspan="3">Seminar</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Schedule</td>
        <th rowspan="2">Topic</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="1">Begin</th>
        <th colspan="1">End</th>
    </tr>

    <!--MONDAY-->

    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Monday</th>
        <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
        <td rowspan="2">5:00 am</td>
        <td>Introduction to XML</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
    </tr>

    <!--TUESDAY-->

    <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">Tuesday</th>
        <td>8:00 am</td>
        <td>11:00 am</td>
        <td>XPath</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>11:00 pm</td>
        <td>2:00 pm</td>
        <td rowspan="2">XSL transformations</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2:00 pm</td>
        <td>5:00 pm</td>
    </tr>

    <!--WEDNESDAY-->
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Wednesday</th>
        <td rowspan="2">8:00 am</td>
        <td rowspan="2">12:00 pm</td>
        <td>XSL Formatting Objects</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Validity: DTD and Relax NG</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Same code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/GokulnathP/pen/BaQqowy?editors=1000)

Comment: Im trying to get XPATH and XSL transformations to be equal